# How to make icon(position:absolute) clickabe inside a input[type file]?

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript

i want to create a image upload button, in which i can click the trash-icon to delete the uploaded image..

But due to `position:absolute` of icon when i click on icon, its opens dialog box for file upload.

Can i avoid this by using CSS
i tried using `pointer-event:none` but couldn't succeed, Am using this in angular project

```css
.upload-btn {
     width: 100%;
     height: 144px;
     background: #fff;
     border: 2px dashed #dae2e8;
     box-sizing: border-box;
     border-radius: 16px;
     background-image: url('https://customercare.igloosoftware.com/.api2/api/v1/communities/10068556/previews/thumbnails/4fc20722-5368-e911-80d5-b82a72db46f2?width=680&height=680&crop=False');
     background-repeat: no-repeat;
     background-position: center 27px;
     position: relative;
   background-size:30px;
}
 .upload-btn .upload-text {
     font-size: 14px;
     position: absolute;
     left: 50%;
     bottom: 24px;
     transform: translateX(-50%);
     padding-left: 16px;
     padding-right: 16px;
     width: 100%;
     text-align: center;
}
 .upload-btn .upload-img {
     position: absolute;
     left: 50%;
     top: 24px;
     width: 62px;
     height: 62px;
     border-radius: 8px;
     transform: translateX(-50%);
     pointer-events: none;
}
 .upload-btn .upload-delete {
     position: absolute;
     right: 0;
     top: 15px;
     width: 62px;
     height: 62px;
     border-radius: 8px;
     pointer-events: none;
     text-align: right;
     background-color: transparent;
}
 .upload-btn .upload-delete i {
     pointer-events: all;
     padding: 15px 17px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.5.0/font/bootstrap-icons.css">
<div class="row row-24 mb-24">
  <div class="col-4">
    <label for="company-logo" class="form-label">Company                                      Logo</label>
    <label for="company-logo" class="upload-btn ">
    <div class="upload-text"> Drop your image here or <span class="text-primary">Browse</span></div>
                            <div class="upload-delete">
                                <i class="bi bi-trash"></i>
                            </div>
                            <input type="file"  class="form-control" name="" id="company-logo" placeholder="" hidden>
                        </label>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: can you give this on stackblitz?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you put the "icon" into a `<button>` tag, it wont open the file picker.

```css
.upload-btn {
     width: 100%;
     height: 144px;
     background: #fff;
     border: 2px dashed #dae2e8;
     box-sizing: border-box;
     border-radius: 16px;
     background-image: url('https://customercare.igloosoftware.com/.api2/api/v1/communities/10068556/previews/thumbnails/4fc20722-5368-e911-80d5-b82a72db46f2?width=680&height=680&crop=False');
     background-repeat: no-repeat;
     background-position: center 27px;
     position: relative;
   background-size:30px;
}
 .upload-btn .upload-text {
     font-size: 14px;
     position: absolute;
     left: 50%;
     bottom: 24px;
     transform: translateX(-50%);
     padding-left: 16px;
     padding-right: 16px;
     width: 100%;
     text-align: center;
}
 .upload-btn .upload-img {
     position: absolute;
     left: 50%;
     top: 24px;
     width: 62px;
     height: 62px;
     border-radius: 8px;
     transform: translateX(-50%);
     pointer-events: none;
}
 .upload-btn .upload-delete {
     position: absolute;
     right: 0;
     top: 15px;
     width: 62px;
     height: 62px;
     border-radius: 8px;
     pointer-events: none;
     text-align: right;
     background-color: transparent;
}
 .upload-btn .upload-delete i {
     pointer-events: all;
     padding: 15px 17px;
}
.trashBtn {
 border: none;
 background: rgba(0,0,0,0);
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.5.0/font/bootstrap-icons.css">
<div class="row row-24 mb-24">
  <div class="col-4">
    <label for="company-logo" class="form-label">Company                                      Logo</label>
    <label for="company-logo" class="upload-btn ">
    <div class="upload-text"> Drop your image here or <span class="text-primary">Browse</span></div>
                            <div class="upload-delete">
                            <button class="trashBtn">
                                <i class="bi bi-trash"></i>
                             </button>
                            </div>
                            <input type="file"  class="form-control" name="" id="company-logo" placeholder="" hidden>
                        </label>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason why your example is failing is that you pretty much have a button inside another button, which is *no bueno*.
To solve this you should move your `delete icon` outside of your `label` and keep it as a sibling, while at the same time you try to align it where you want it.

EDIT: if you care about accessibility, I would advise you to not do a button inside another button; although this answer is not that much better, at least you won't have as many issues with it.

Here's my suggestion for you:

```css
#wrappingDiv {
  position: relative;
}

.upload-btn {
  width: 100%;
  height: 144px;
  background: #fff;
  border: 2px dashed #dae2e8;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-radius: 16px;
  background-image: url("https://customercare.igloosoftware.com/.api2/api/v1/communities/10068556/previews/thumbnails/4fc20722-5368-e911-80d5-b82a72db46f2?width=680&height=680&crop=False");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center 27px;
  position: relative;
  background-size: 30px;
}

.upload-btn .upload-text {
  font-size: 14px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  bottom: 24px;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  padding-left: 16px;
  padding-right: 16px;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

.upload-btn .upload-img {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 24px;
  width: 62px;
  height: 62px;
  border-radius: 8px;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  pointer-events: none;
}

.upload-delete {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 30px;
  width: 62px;
  height: 62px;
  padding: 15px 17px;
  border-radius: 8px;
  text-align: right;
  background-color: transparent;
  z-index: 10;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.5.0/font/bootstrap-icons.css">
    <div class="row row-24 mb-24">
      <div class="col-4">
        <div id="wrappingDiv">
        <label for="company-logo" class="form-label">Company      Logo</label>
        <label for="company-logo" class="upload-btn ">
          <div class="upload-text"> Drop your image here or <span class="text-primary">Browse</span></div>
          <input type="file"  class="form-control" name="" id="company-logo" placeholder="" hidden>
        </label>
        <div class="upload-delete">
          <i class="bi bi-trash"></i>
        </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also `evt.stopPropagation()` inside the icon click handler.

Or don't wrap the `input` and icon with the `label` and use an `id` to associate form label and control.